# Umbraco and Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, umbraco, windows-authentication, umbraco7

My team tries to setup an intranet portal powered by Umbraco which requires **Windows Authentication** for authenticating its users that are stored as (Umbraco) Members.

Currently we have done the following:

1. In the **Authentication Feature of IIS**, we enabled only Windows Authentication at the root of the web site (all other authentication options are disabled).
2. In **Web Config**, we changed the Authentication settings mode attribute from Forms to Windows.
3. The username of the Members is stored in the domain\username format.

That works fine as far it concerns authentication and authorization of members in the front end. But in the back office (that requires Forms Authentication), it does not work well with the above settings, as sometimes the browser displays the authentication popup window and requires for the back office user to enter his (domain) credentials or sometimes randomly terminates the back office user's session and logs user out.

Is there any suggested way for implementing Windows Authentication for Umbraco portals that does not raise such issues in the back office?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using AD authentication for the backoffice?  There are packages that support this behavior.